# Is it possible to assign a lead to a certain business division in OroCRM (community edition)?

Tags: orocrm

I have about 10.000 leads and I have different callcenters that can use these leads to call the customers. Callcenter A is not allowed to see the leads that Callcenter B can see, etc. Is it possible to assign a lead to a certain callcenter (assuming this works using business divisions in oroCRM)? If there is any other method applicable I'd love to hear it as well ofcourse.

Answer (score 0):

The Lead entity has `owner_type: user`, it means that permissions are managed up to the user level. With role permissions configuration you can make the Lead entity belong to the whole division. for this, you have to set the appropriate permission to Division level on a Lead entity for the role that needs access to all the Leads created by users from the same division.

[image]